# showing syntax error while using sequence in mysql

Tags: sequence, mysql-error-1064

-- creating table

```
 create table student( studID int(10),
    -> name varchar(100),
    -> roll_no int(20));
```

--inserting values in table

```
insert into student(name,roll_no) values("suraj",79);
insert into student(name,roll_no) values("ajay",70);
```

--creating sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE stud_seq AS INT
    -> START WITH 100
    -> INCREMENT BY 1;
```

--error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'SEQUENCE stud_seq AS INT

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are confusing things.  In MySql, you use a sequence by declaring an autoincrement field

```
 create table student ( 
  studID int autoincrement,
  name varchar(100),
  roll_no int(20);
```

Now, `studID` will start from 1 and automatically increment for each record inserted where the value is not specified or is null.

So

```
insert into student(name,roll_no) values("suraj",79);
insert into student(name,roll_no) values("ajay",70);
```

will allocate 1 to suraj and 2 to ajay.

To change the value of the autoinc field to 100

```
alter table student
auto_increment=100
```

More Information at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_autoincrement.asp)
or [mysqltutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.net/mysql-sequence/)